# How come Eclipse won't refresh?

Tags: eclipse, refresh, project

Whenever I press F5, click the refresh option, or even reload my project, nothing happens. I don't understand why Eclipse would be doing this. Please help.

Comment: Where (in which view or editor) did you press F5 and what makes you say _"nothing happens"_? Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What are you expecting Refresh to do? This just looks for new or changed files in the project, if there aren't any nothing will happen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.